# qemu-img convert of VMDK written to block device: invalid footer

Tags: convert, vmdk

This is a weird one, so please bear with me.

I've got a tool that does the following things:

1. Upload a disk image (VMDK) via an HTTP API (Flask).
2. On the API side, it creates a temporary block device (for completeness, it makes an RBD volume and maps it).
3. It writes the uploaded VMDK to the temporary block device.
4. It (tries to) run `qemu-img convert` to convert the VMDK image on the temporary block device to one on a real device.

The purpose of this is to allow one to upload VMDK images and then convert them into RAW images for use by KVM VMs.

However, you can ignore the above; this is simply the X to my Y so you don't think I'm stuck in some absurd X-Y conundrum; this is how it *has* to work otherwise I need an arbitrary amount of RAM on the API system which is obviously not viable. I can replicate the issue simply by creating the volume (at any given size), `dd`ing the VMDK to it, and then running `qemu-img convert` on it, so it's not my API causing the issue.

In order to do the above, I read the size of the VMDK file using Python's `os.path.getsize()` function, which matches the size that `ls -l` presents. The temporary block device is sized according to this value.

Here's the problem: once the VMDK is on the temporary block device, the attempt to do `qemu-img convert` on it fails with an "invalid footer".

```
qemu-img: Could not open '/dev/rbd/vms/test_import': Invalid footer
```

I've found that it does this with VMDK files whenever the target is a different size from the VMDK file, e.g. if it's too small or, annoyingly, *too large*. So clearly I have some sort of issue with the size of the temporary block device.

However I've tried to correctly size this temporary volume based on various values: `ls -l`, Python `os.stat()`, `du -B 1` (which gives a different value), but it fails every time. The image is also sparse, so getting the size from `qemu-img info` doesn't help. I've tried slowly incrementing these sizes on either side but no dice either (so it's not some obvious off-by-1 error).

So, here's my question: how can I find the *actual, real, not-going-to-throw-this-error* size of the VMDK that qemu-img would *expect* it to be, so it doesn't become "corrupted" like this?

Answer (score 0):

And of course simply by posting it and reading it back, I figured out the issue. And it's simply what I said: the RBD image is the wrong size. *Why* it's the wrong size is that how I was creating it was failing to take into account 1024 vs 1000 when converting human-readable values to bytes.